# Adding Multiple Source Maps in Gulp Task

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, minify

I am currently trying to generate two sourcemaps in Gulp for the SASS files that I am piping in (regular bootstrap file and minified bootstrap file). When I write the source maps the second time, it tries to read in the regular un-minified source map and throws an error. Do I have to separate this into two tasks or is there a way to keep this as one task for the SASS and map building? Thanks in advance here's the code!

```
// Load Node Modules/Plugins
    import gulp from 'gulp';
    import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
    import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
    import del from 'del';
    var gutil = require('gulp-util');


    const reload = browserSync.reload;
    const $ = gulpLoadPlugins();

    // Remove existing docs and dist build
    gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['docs/dist', 'dist']));


    // Build LibSass files
    gulp.task('styles', function() {
      gulp.src('./scss/bootstrap.scss')
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.sass().on('error', $.sass.logError))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}))
        .pipe($.rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe($.minifyCss())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
    });



    // Build JavaScript files 
    gulp.task('scripts', function() {
      return gulp.src(['js/src/util.js', 'js/src/alert.js', 'js/src/button.js', 'js/src/carousel.js', 'js/src/collapse.js', 'js/src/dropdown.js', 'js/src/modal.js', 'js/src/scrollspy.js', 'js/src/tab.js', 'js/src/tooltip.js', 'js/src/popover.js'])
        .pipe($.babel())
        .pipe($.concat('./bootstrap.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
    });





    // Watch tasks
    gulp.task('watch', function() {     
           gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
           gulp.watch('js/src/*.js', ['scripts']);
    });

    gulp.task('dist', ['styles', 'scripts']);

    gulp.task('default', ['clean'], () => {
      gulp.start('dist');
    });
```